# Binding to Table Storage in v2 Azure Functions using CloudTable

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

So according to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1548), support for `IQueryable` was dropped for v2  Azure Functions. This is also reflected in [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---usage). That doc also mentions that `CloudTable` could be used to bind to Table storage, however no specific information or examples are provided.
In a minimal working example, how would a Table Storage binding for a v2 Azure Function look like (for, say, reading all rows of a table from table storage)?
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```cs
[FunctionName("TestFunction")]
public static async Task Run(
    [QueueTrigger("test-queue")] string message,
    [Table("testTable")] CloudTable testTable)
{
    var querySegment = testTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<ResultEntity>(), null);
    foreach (ResultEntity item in querySegment.Result)
    {
        // Access table storage items here
    }
}
```

A full working example is available [here](https://gist.github.com/MrMikeFloyd/dacb049eaa1d35bd4f93eb02728a9f39).

Comment: Cheers @Mikhail for the quick response. Using `ExecuteQuery` yields to `'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteQuery' and no extension method 'ExecuteQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [readCtab]`. I included `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;` from Package `WindowsAzure.Storage`. I tried with both Version 8.6.0 and 9.0 with no success.

Comment: @MikeFloyd I copied it from full .NET framework example. I've now updated the sample with `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` which I used on .NET Standard. Could you try this one?

Comment: your example still required some fiddling around, but it definitely pointed me in the right direction. I have a working example now, see my answer below. Full example [here](https://gist.github.com/MrMikeFloyd/dacb049eaa1d35bd4f93eb02728a9f39). Thanks a lot for your pointers!

Comment: @MikeFloyd Cool, welcome. I think you could just extend my answer instead of copying it over, but whatever works for you.

Comment: Totally makes sense @Mikhail. I removed my duplicate answer and extended your code sample to match the working sample. Cheers again for your quick and on-point help.

Comment: I was missing the Table attribute, having only these Nuget packages in my .NET Standard 2.0 project: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.23 and NETStandard.Library 2.0.3. After digging I found out that this attribute is in package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.0.1, which I had to include.

Comment: Just a note: this is not working with the latest SDKs. You'll end up with an error saying `Can't bind Table to type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable'.` - possible reason: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3784

Comment: @Krumelur were you able to find a workaround for this?