# Binding to Table Storage in v2 Azure Functions using CloudTable with partitionKey and rowKey Filter

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am using Azure Functions V2 ( .Net core 2.1 ) 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922485/binding-to-table-storage-in-v2-azure-functions-using-cloudtable) post explains **Binding Table Storage in V2 Azure Function**

But what I am looking for is provide Filter condition along with the `[Table]` attribute.

e.g. In below example I would like to fetch only records whose 'PartitionKey' is {partitionKey} and RowKey is {rowKey} , where {partitionKey} and {rowKey} belongs to routes.

```
[FunctionName("Function2")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> GetPerson(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "api/person/{partitionKey}/{rowKey}")] HttpRequest req
            , string partitionKey
            , string rowKey
            , ILogger log
            , [Table("Test", "{partitionKey}",{rowKey} , Connection = "MyConnection")]CloudTable cloudTable
            )
    {
       //I am expecting only records with specified partitionKey and rowKey but its fetching all records like 'select * from Test' 
       var querySegment = cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<MyEntity>(), null);
        foreach (var item in querySegment.Result)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"{item.PartitionKey} - {item.RowKey} - {item.Name}");
        }
```

**Expected :** 
   `cloudTable` should contain only one row with specified partitionKey and rowKey 
**Actual**
   `cloudTable` contains all the records

I am looking for something like `CosmosDb` binding

```
[FunctionName("TestFunction")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "regos/{queryStringParameter}")]
        [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "MyDb",
            collectionName: "Table",
            CreateIfNotExists = true,
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnectionString",                
            SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table t where t.Col = {queryStringParameter}")]
            IEnumerable<dynamic> list,
```

Above code workds perfectly fine with the Azure Functions V2

any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

Try the suggestions mentioned in the [link](https://gist.github.com/MrMikeFloyd/dacb049eaa1d35bd4f93eb02728a9f39)

Learn more on Table storage input binding supports the following [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---usage)

```html
[FunctionName("TestFunction")]
public static async Task Run(
    [QueueTrigger("test-queue")] string message,
    [Table("testTable")] CloudTable testTable)
{
    var querySegment = testTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<ResultEntity>(), null);
    foreach (ResultEntity item in querySegment.Result)
    {
        // Access table storage items here
    }
}
```

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.